# How to invoke an npm script from a parent folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I created an express-based backend (in folder A) and a related react-based front-end project (in folder B) respectively. Now I put B inside A for the following benefits:

1. I don't need to copy files from font-end build to server project anymore because `A/server.js` can serve files from `A/B/build` directly.
2. No need to worry about the cross origin request errors.
3. They look like one project and are easier to manage in GitHub.
   But can I run `npm run buildjs` from folder A, which actually runs `npm run build` in folder B? I guess it has much to do with the npm run-script usage.

Comment: is the `front-end` package also a service, or just static files?

Comment: They are static files

Answer (score 10):

This can be done using `--prefix <path>`. From folder A:

```
npm run --prefix ./B build
```

You could add the following to `A/package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "buildjs": "npm run --prefix ./B build"
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. copy is not a problem, just make it be automatic. Introduce a deployment step is not bad.
2. there will not be any `cross origin` problem because you are serving `front-end` as static files. or at least the `cross origin` problem should do no matter with it
3. people first. split or not split projects, depends on developers